# Weird invalid block type error in Magento

Tags: magento

> 2012-08-23T09:39:06+00:00 ERR (3):  exception 'Mage_Core_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid block type:
>   Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit_Form' in
>   /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/Mage.php:594

**Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Edit.php**

```
<?php 
class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        /*
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'brands';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_brand';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';    
        parent::__construct();
        */

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'brands';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_brand';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';

        $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
                  'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
                  'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
                  'class' => 'save',
        ), -100);
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('brands')->__('Save Example'));

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('form_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'edit_form');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'edit_form');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('example_data') && Mage::registry('example_data')->getId())
        {
            return Mage::helper('brands')->__('Edit Example "%s"', $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('example_data')->getName()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('brands')->__('New Example');
        }
    }

}
```

**Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Form.php**

```
<?php

class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExampleData())
        {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExamplelData();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getExampleData(null);
        }
        elseif (Mage::registry('example_data'))
        {
            $data = Mage::registry('example_data')->getData();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array();
        }

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                'method' => 'post',
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);

        $this->setForm($form);

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('example_form', array(
             'legend' =>Mage::helper('brands')->__('Example Information')
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Name'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'name',
             'note'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('The name of the example.'),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('description', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Description'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'description',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('other', 'text', array(
             'label'     => Mage::helper('brands')->__('Other'),
             'class'     => 'required-entry',
             'required'  => true,
             'name'      => 'other',
        ));

        $form->setValues($data);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

I still get the same error with this.

```
<?php

class Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is named:

> Desbest_Brands_Block_Adminhtml_Brand_**Edit**_Form

But it exists in the file location

> Desbest/Brands/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Form.php

You're missing an Edit folder :)